# Relational query for universally quantified formula

Tags: database-theory, relational-algebra

My university is participating in the implementation of a library borrowing managing system at Richelieu National Library in France.

I received the order to formulate the query: "find all users having borrowed every book" in relational Algebra, in relational Calculus and in SQL (which would probably not happen, probably librarians want to test the limits of the database).

The database has the following pattern (the primary keys are in bold):

Borrowing(**People, Book, DateBorrowing**, ExpectedReturnDate, EffectiveReturnDate)
Lateness(**People, Book, DateBorrowing**, LatenessFee)

I tried

$$\Pi_{People}(Borrowing)\div\Pi_{People}(\sigma_{Book} (Borrowing))$$

But It seemed to be wrong as far as to do  $r\div s$, $S\subseteq R$  is needed, which seems not to be the case, but why? I'm still talking about people, isn't it?

I then tried the following relational calculus formula:

$$\{t.People|Borrowing(t)\wedge(\forall u Borrowing(u)\Rightarrow t.DateBorrowing)\}$$

To find every books that have a borrowing date. I know this calcuation is false but I don't know how to do better...

Then in SQL:

```
SELECT People FROM Borrowing
    WHERE FORALL Books EXISTS DateBorrowing
```

That is what I tried and I know that is not the right way to "find all users having borrowed every book". Can you help me expressing correctely such a querry?

Answer (score 3):

SQL does not have a universal quantifier, but an equivalent can be constructed from the existential one, through a [normalization process](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/wccce/program00/kawash/kawash.html) similar to Skolemization: $$\forall x P(x) \iff \nexists x \neg P(x)$$

In your case, you want the users for which there does not exist a book that they have not borrowed:

```
select * from people p
where not exists
  (select * from books b
   where b.id not in 
     (select book_id 
      from borrowings
      where people_id=p.id)
  )
```

(Note that I have assumed tables for people and books to represent their existence separately from the borrowings table, which, for instance, may be empty at the inception of the system.)

Comment: This a very nice answer, I perfectly understand the link you do between the $\forall$ with the Skolemization in SQL! And I upvoted consequently. But I was looking for one in Relational algebra and relational calculus...

Answer (score 1):

For the SQL part:

First, you want to determine how many books there are:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT book) FROM Borrowing)
```

Next, you want to `SELECT` those people who have Borrowed every different book - so one way to do this is by checking that the `COUNT` of `DISTINCT` books for each person is the same as the `COUNT` of all `DISTINCT` books:

```
 SELECT people
 FROM Borrowing
 GROUP BY people
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Book) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Book) FROM Borrowing);
```

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]. This site is a computer science site, not a code writing site. Please explain why this query answers the question. On this site, the explanation is the important part, not the code.

Comment: @Gilles I will edit

Answer (score -3):

select distinct people
from borrowing 
group by people
having count(book) in (select count(book) from borrowing);

Comment: Welcome to [cs.se]. This site is a computer science site, not a code writing site. Please explain why this query answers the question. On this site, the explanation is the important part, not the code.